# Awk -v variable assignment

Tags: linux, shell, awk

*nix / awk newbie here.  I'm wondering what is wrong with my syntax on the simple awk -v example below.

```
# this line produces the expected result, 'xyz'
echo "abc xyz" | /usr/bin/awk -v ttl="$2" '{print $2}'

# but this line does not, it prints a blank line
echo "abc xyz" | /usr/bin/awk -v ttl="$2" '{print ttl}'
```

What am I doing incorrectly with the -v option above ?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: what is that you actually _want_ to do?

Comment: I want to use the hours being passed in the second argument to the date command being executed in the awk script (for now it is hardcoded, but would like to use the ttl value.  I suspect I'm having quoting/escaping issues here):  echo "2022-07-28T18:42:52Z -72" | /usr/bin/awk '{ttl=$2;print ttl}; $1 <= "'$(date -d"now -72 hours" -Ins --utc)'" { print "expired" }'

Comment: soo, you don't really want to print that second field at all? But instead you want to use it as one of the arguments to the `date` command? Or, to get even more to the point, you have an line that consists of a timestamp, and some number of hours, and you want to find out if that timestamp is that much in the past? E.g. `2022-07-28T18:42:52Z -72` should give "expired", since it's more than 72 h from that date, but `2022-07-27T11:22:33Z -168` should not, since it's less than 168 h from that date? I'd probably do that in the shell (not awk), with a couple of invocations of `date`...

Comment: Yes thanks ilkkachu, that sounds like an easier plan than using awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your first example:

> ```
> echo "abc xyz" | /usr/bin/awk -v ttl="$2" '{print $2}'
> ```

This sets the `awk` variable to the second shell script parameter¹. The `awk` code then ignores that variable and prints the second field of each line in its *stdin*, ie. `xyz` for the one and only line. Note that were you to print `ttl` you'd find it empty.

Basically, the first `$2` is a shell parameter expansion, performed by the shell, and the second is an `awk` field (the `$` operator applied to the number 2, you could also have written it `$ 2` or `$ (1 + 1)`...), evaluated for each line of *stdin* by `awk`.

Now let's consider the second example:

> ```
> echo "abc xyz" | /usr/bin/awk -v ttl="$2" '{print ttl}'
> ```

This sets the `awk` variable to the second shell script parameter¹. The `awk` code then prints that variable, which is empty, for each line of *stdin*.

In the shell context, `$2` is the second parameter to a shell script. When you run this directly from the command line there is no "second parameter"² so it's empty. However, when you run it as a script it may have a value.

```
#!/bin/sh -
printf 'This is $2: %s\n' "$2"
```

Save that in the file `demo`, make it executable `chmod a+x demo`. Now run it and observe:

```
./demo one
./demo one two
./demo one two three
```

Unfortunately you haven't told us what you're trying to achieve, so I can't suggest a solution for your requirement. But hopefully you'll get there with the information in these answers.

If you wanted for `ttl` to specify which field you want to output, you'd use:

```
$ echo "abc xyz" | awk -v ttl=2 '{print $ ttl}'
xyz
```

---

<sup>¹ though beware that with the `-v var=value` syntax, escape sequences such as `\n`, `\v`... in the value are expanded by awk, so if `$2`  contains `\n`, `ttl` will contain a newline character instead of `\n`</sup>

<sup>² unless you have run `set one two three` beforehand or possibly `2=two` or `argv=(one two three)` in some shells which are ways to change the positional parameters dynamically in a shell.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers. I now am able to print the variable.  However, what I am trying to do is determine if a date has exceeded the number of hours.  Both are passed in to the awk command by a previous command, but for the sake of simplicity I'll give the example below using an echo:

Comment: echo "2022-07-28T18:42:52Z -72" | /usr/bin/awk '{ttl=$2;print ttl}; $1 <= "'$(date -d"now -72 hours" -Ins --utc)'" { print "expired" }'

Comment: In the date command above, how can I make use of the ttl variable?  It seems as if I'm not escaping/quoting properly.  I have it hardcoded as -72 hours above, but need to change that to be the value of ttl.  Thanks again so much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In second case `$2` have no value. `$2` have value inside the `awk` script. if you set something like:

```
AAA="test123"
echo "abc xyz" | /usr/bin/awk -v ttl="$AAA" '{print ttl}'
```

it will print the value of variable `AAA` which is get from your shell environment.

If you explicitely want to use in `awk` specific variable you can do it on this way:

```
echo "abc xyz" | /usr/bin/awk  '{ttl=$2;print ttl}'
```